# Searching in a hash map

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, hashmap

I was wondering if the time complexity for the following code would be O(n)(in average time or in the context of coding interviews):

```
for i in len(range(ls)):

   Dict = {}
   ......
   define foo
   if foo not in Dict.keys():
       Dict[foo] = 0
```

Comment: It's `O(n)` on Python 3, and `O(n**2)` on Python 2 (where `.keys()` returns a `list` which are `O(n)` to do containment tests on, rather than `O(1)` for `dict`). Drop the `.keys()` and it's `O(n)` on both.

Answer (score 1):

In python 2 it is O(n), because keys() returns a list.
In Python 3 it is O(1), because keys() returns a KeysView object, which is inherited from Set, see https://python.readthedocs.io/en/v2.7.2/library/collections.html#collections.KeysView